# Need help with VBS Classes

Tags: class, scripting, vbscript

```
Class GetUserName
Private internal_Username
Private internal_strComputer
Private internal_objWMIService
Private internal_colComputer
Private internal_objComputer

Public Property Get EmployeeName
    strComputer = "."
    Set internal_objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set internal_colComputer = internal_objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
    For Each objComputer In internal_colComputer
        internal_Username = LCase(Right(internal_colComputer.UserName, Len(internal_colComputer.UserName) - Len(Left(internal_colComputer.UserName, 7))))
    Next
    EmployeeName = internal_Username
End Property
End Class
Dim objEmployee
Set objEmployee = New GetUserName

WScript.Echo objEmployee.EmployeeName
```

I get an error saying

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error (13, 4) : Object doesn't support this property or method: 'internal_colComputer.UserName'
```

Comment: btw, what's the point of `Len(Left(internal_colComputer.UserName, 7))`. It will always either be 7, or throw an error if `UserName` is less than 7 chars.

Comment: The user names on our systems is CONTOS\firstname.lastname . We want to only retain the firstname.lastname and not have the CONTOS\ as part of the username

Comment: That's fine, but there's no point doing the long Len function. just use 7 - the Len... will evaluate to 7 anyway as that's the length of the `Left` part that you're taking. A clearer alternative would be to use `Len("CONTOS\")` - this makes it more clear what that bit is doing.

Comment: I did it this way incase the domain name changes to something else. This would prevent rewriting the code to match the new domain name. But I see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
internal_Username = LCase(Right(internal_colComputer.UserName, Len(internal_colComputer.UserName) - Len(Left(internal_colComputer.UserName, 7))))
```

to

```
internal_Username = LCase(Right(objComputer.UserName, Len(objComputer.UserName) - Len(Left(objComputer.UserName, 7))))
```

I would suspect (although I'm not sure) that `UserName` is a property of the `objComputer`, not the collection that you're looping through.

Comment: Works for me if I make this change

Answer (score 0):

```
>> cnHeadLen = 8
>> s = "CONTOS\firstname.lastname"
>> WScript.Echo Mid( s, cnHeadLen )
>>
firstname.lastname
```